# how to Configure search:search options to create cts element query having second parameter as cts-and query with empty sequence?

Tags: xquery, marklogic

I am using search:search API for searching in Marklogic.

I want to form a **cts element query** as given below

```
cts:element-query(fn:QName("element-name"), cts:and-query(()))
```

What would be the search options configuration (constraints) to form cts query as mentioned above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is a top-level constraint, how about passing it as the additional query (an option for search:search)

Comment: Thanks, It is working perfectly. one more question, Is there any way to sort the results based on a particular element present in matched xml documents?

Comment: Glad it worked. If the answer is correct, please mark it as so in order for people to focus on tickets with no solution. As for your other question, please ask it separately (preferably with a sample XML file and sample search config) in a new ticket. Answering second questions hides them in the comments and is not as helpful to people using stack overflow as a knowledgebase.